# How to add a common text after the price in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

Hi I want to add "VAT excl " text after the product price in single product page . How can i do this . Which file i need to edit . Please suggest the correct path

```
app/design/frontend/mythemes/default/Magento_Catalog/templates/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method - 1:  If you want to display custom text only in product view page, then create catalog_product_view.xml in your custom theme

**app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.text" template="Magento_Catalog::view/customtext.phtml" after="product.info.price"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now create customtext.phtml and add your custom text

app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/view/customtext.phtml

Now flush the cache and check

Method - 2: If you want to display custom text after price at everywhere then override final_price.phtml

FROM

**vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml**

TO

**app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml**

Method - 3: Last and the most simple way to do it with CSS

```
 .product-info-price .price:after {
    content: 'Custom Text';
}
```

Comment: i tried first method by adding files on this path cache and static contents cleared but didn't works, any idea why this happening, thank you
/app/design/frontend/maintheme/subtheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
/app/design/frontend/maintheme/subtheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/customtext.phtml

Comment: I want to add a custom text through out the website, so followed the second method, but it's does not work